# closing an active excel file knowing fraction of the name

Tags: vba, excel

I have opened a file given the fraction of the name, where i equals to 142 as per below code.
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath3 & "*" & i & ".*"

After switching back and forth between other files is it possible to return back to this file and close it? I cant figure out how to Reference/Activate it, given I only have fraction of the name.

Thanks

Comment: Use Instr() function to check for partial string matches and set to a workbook variable to reference back to them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, after you open this file it's automatically activated, so I'd make it like:

```
Dim fileName as String
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath3 & "" & i & "."
fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

and from this moment you can close your file at any time with something like:

```
Workbooks(fileName ).Close (False)
```

use (False) only if you don't want to save it

Comment: you have a typo here but its all good :)  fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Comment: thnx. Corrected